# Square usage with multiple client websites

Tags: square

The firm I work for sells and installs a website under the client's desired url. This is my first time dealing with any type of payment system.

I've created a SquareUp application in my own account but am lost as to whether each client website needs their own SquareUp application. I realize that there is the option for my SquareUp application to be given permission to access other SquareUp accounts.

Edit:
I think the OAuth API would work if I had many clients accessing the same website but each client has their own installed copy of the website we sell.

So lets say my firm makes a hotel reservation website that can be easily customized through settings. So we sell a website to Bob's Motel and his new url is www.bobsmotel.com and his web installation is complete separate from other of our clients.

In the SquareUp Application Dashboard, under my SquareUp account, does Bob's Motel get its own Application or does Bob in his SquareUp account create an application and I use those ID's in my settings file?

Comment: After more thought, I think I do need to create a SquareUp application for each website.  Each SU app would need OAuth permission to the specific client SU account.

Answer (score 0):

Square’s OAuth API will be what you’ll use to let up to 500 Square merchants authorize your application. Before you get started, please visit Square’s Developer Doc for more information about our OAuth API (https://docs.connect.squareup.com/basics/oauth/overview).